# How to increase a number for a certain percentage (say %10) expotential number of times (say 20) and then decrease it to base value again?

Tags: math, formula

I basically have a number, say `100`.

I can increase it by **10 percent every time**. So, :

- 1st run it would become `110`,
- 2nd `121`,
- 3rd `133` and so on.

I can have count of how much the value was increased. **But how to expotentialy decrease the amount knowing the number of times it has been increased back to 100?**

Is there a way to do it with simple math op like ** instead of looping the current value amount of times it has been altered by 10 percents?

I know I can just store it in additionl column like `base_number=100` or something when I need the basic value, but I would like to know if its possible to do by one-liner calculations?

Comment: Well, your question is not about programmation but maths :/

Comment: @MickaelLeger  I guess that might be true

Comment: @MickaelLeger thank you for the edit

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about programming.

Comment: @HighPerformanceMark though I will be using PHP but all answers are implementable in any language so it does not matter I guess. Anyways, I changed the tags to 'correct' ones.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So your basic question is, how do you invert and find `x_0` given a known `n` and:

```
x_n = x_0 * 1.1^n
```

Looks like we can simply divide through by `1.1^n`

```
x_n/(1.1^n) = x_0
```

So you can either calculate `1.1^n` with `pow(1.1, n)` and divide `x_n` (your "increased" value) by that, or just loop and reduce like you increased:

```
//1.
$original = $increased/pow(1.1, n);

//2.
$original = $increased;
for ($i = 0; $i < n; $i++) {
    $original = $original / 1.1;
}
```

So in your example, let's say our `$increased` is known to be 133, and `n=3`. Then using the first method:

```
$original = 133 / (1.1^3) = 133 / 1.33 = 100
```

Comment: Yes,thank you, it does work! Just tested it by increasing the value (100) expotentially by 10% 20 times (672) and used the 1st formula, works like a charm with only one line! One more question: how to increase the same number (100) by 10% expotentialy using one-liner?

Comment: The very first equation in my answer can be used to one-line the increment process as well. Just replace `1.1^n` with `pow(1.1, n)`

Comment: Yep,thanks! Btw from PHP 56+ you can ** op like 4**4, Its faster and more convenient to the than power function but does exacty same thing!

Answer (score 1):

Let's make a simple example and try to find a formula :

```
100 * 1.10 = 110;
110 * 1.10 = 121;
121 * 1.10 = 133.1;
```

So right now we have :

```
basic_number (will be bn) * increase_value (will be iv) = basic_number2;
bn2 * iv = bn3;
bn3 * iv = bn4;
```

We can write it too :

```
bn * iv = bn2;
bn * iv * iv = bn3;
bn * iv * iv * iv = bn4;
```

And so we have the beginning of a formula :

```
bn * iv^3 = bn4;
```

Now what you will have as data according to your post is :

```
X : the number of increase
bnX : the basic number increase X time
iv : the increase value
```

And you want to find bn according to those value :

```
bn * iv^X = bnX;
bn = bnX / iv^X;
bn = bnX / (iv * iv * iv ... * iv); // X time
```

So with PHP it could look like this :

```
$X = /* the number of incease */;
$bnX = /* the basic number increase X time */;
$iv = /* the increase value */;

for($i = 0; $i < $X; $i++) {
    $bnX = $bnX / $iv;
}
```

This way you will if you `echo $bnX;` at the end of the loop, you should get your basic number !

You can try to make a php formula to do it and use it every time :

```
// 1/ Using a loop
function getBasicNumber($bnX, $X, $iv) {
    for($i = 0; $i < $X; $i++) {
        $bnX = $bnX / $iv;
    }
    return $bnX;
}
```

---

**EDIT**

```
// 2/ Using pow
function getBasicNumber($bnX, $X, $iv) {
    return $bnX / pow($X, $iv);
}

// 3/ Using '**'
function getBasicNumber($bnX, $X, $iv) {
    return $bnX / $X**$iv;
}
```

---

This way you just have to do :

```
echo getBasicNumber(133.1, 3, 1.10); // 100 here for example
```

Hope it's clear? But still, it's more a maths problem than a programming one

Comment: I always extracted the percentage value by doing $n+(($n/100)*prcnt, but this $n *1.10 things is very nice! Your answer is also correct same as @CollinD but the one he has is better I think. Thanks though!

Comment: I'm ok his anwser is better because it's more "programming" oriented with the use of `pow` (that I didn't knew before btw, still cool to learn somehting new!), mine was more to understand the logic :)

Comment: Btw, in PHP 5.6 and later you can use 4**4 op instead of pow(4,4)

Comment: Thanks for the information, I edit my anwser just to show it :)